# Why this php code output one

Tags: php

I have this php code with me and i am not able to figure it out could anyone help on this.

```
$x = 3 - 5 % 3;
echo $x;
```

gives 1 in out put.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5 % 3 = 2.

3 - 2 = 1.

There's a specific [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), that causes modulo to be evaluated before minus.

Comment: @Mr.Alien he is waiting for SO to let him accept the answer (15 mins)(I guess)

Comment: Just a note, it seems quite a few people don't know that or forgot it since high school, but this operator precedence is not programming language nor php specific, in regular math * and / (and thus %) are also of higher precedence than + and -

Answer (score 3):

It' s simple math!

% / * operators are first calculated and then
+ -

```
5 % 3 = 2 
3 - 2 = 1
```

If you want to "prevent" this simply add some brackets:

```
$x = (3 - 5) % 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course the answer is correct. PHP parses the code like this `3 - (5 % 3)`
`5 % 3` is `2` and `3 - 2` gives you `1`
`5 % 3` is the remainder of `5 /3`

Answer (score 0):

It's the order of operations. Without parenthesis around the subtraction, the modulo is being evaluated first. Try this:

```
$x = (3 - 5) % 3;
echo $x;
```

Answer (score 0):

`%` has higher presedence then `-`. Check out [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 0):

BODMAS - Brackets Order[^] Division Multiplication Addition Substracion .
For,

```
3 - 5 % 3
```

first,
`5 % 3` gives remainder as `1`
second,
`3 - 1`,
this gives `2`.